# Any way to block/remove keyboard hook in uncontrolled window's Menubar?

Tags: windows, ui-automation

I'm sending keystrokes to an inactive Adobe Flash Projector window with PostMessage, that part works perfectly. I leave it running in the background and it interferes very little with my normal computer usage, which is the intent. The problem comes when I programmatically send the `W` (or less frequently `Q`) key while I happen to be holding `Ctrl` intended for a different windows shortcut. This triggers `Ctrl-Q` or `Ctrl-W`, both of which immediately close the Adobe Flash Projector. `Ctrl-F` and `Ctrl-O` have some undesirable effects as well.

EDIT: I'm not interested in solutions that briefly release the `Ctrl` key.

Is there anyway I can unhook shortcut keys from a third party window? It uses a standard OS menubar across the top of the window which is where the shortcuts are listed, so surely there's a way to reassign, unassign, or block it, right?

In the past I tried using these dlls to break the menu. It made it disappear but didn't break the shortcuts.

```
DllCall("SetMenu", uint, this.id, uint, 0)
hMenu := DllCall("GetSystemMenu", "UInt",this.id, "UInt",1)
DllCall("DestroyMenu", "Uint",hMenu)
```

Sorry for the strange syntax, this is from an early version of my program written in autohotkey.

*The language I'm using now is C#, but I assume the solution uses a .dll, so that's not as important. Feel free to suggest or change my tags.*

Comment: Which method are you using to send keystrokes to the Adobe window?  SendMessage, SendInput, UI Automation, something else?

Comment: "I'm sending keystrokes to an inactive Adobe Flash Projector window with PostMessage" - Gunfulker, first sentence.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote with no explanation, really helpful guys.

Comment: Your best bet is to use SendInput or UI Automation to control the Adobe window instead of PostMessage.  Posting messages is the least reliable way to do that, in part, because you have to way to control the context in which the message arrives.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy AFAIK SendInput doesn't work on **inactive** windows. I don't know much about `UI Automation` but from the descriptions I've read it's the underlying API that allows AutoHotkey to manipulate the position, size, color, and text content of standard windows controls. The only standard windows control in the Adobe Flash Projector is the menu bar. As for controlling the context, the context of my question **is** both things happening at once. Even if SendInput did work on inactive windows, it controls the context by releasing the Ctrl key, which would interfere with other programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the program [Resource Tuner](http://www.restuner.com/download.htm)'s free trial, I opened up `flashplayer_28_sa.exe`, went to Accelerator Table (Apparently accelerator means shortcut in the context of Menus), and deleted the offending shortcuts. Then I saved it, and it failed to save, and I saved it again, and again, and again, and then it worked, although I did nothing differently that time.

I think it would work with other shortcuts for programs with standard windows menus.

Comment: But editing executable files of other programs can be illegal due to EULA. Thus I did not proposed it.

Comment: Yes, it is technically. Everyone should listen to 18C and take that under advisement.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can try to make inactive (`WS_DISABLED` - use `GetWindowStyle` and `SetWindowStyle`) the main window of destination application (the Window that contains menu).
2. You can try to find which functions are used by application and rewrite them in local copy of application with `VirtualProtect` and injecting assembler (dangerous if you have no knowledge about virtualization of memory). Check the application use `GetKeyState` or `GetAsyncKeyState` (it will be visible after opening the application in text editor).
3. You can try:

   `HMENU hMenu=GetMenu(applicationMainWindow);
   SetMenu(applicationMainWindow,0);
   // here send your input with SendMessageW instead of PostMessageW
   SetMenu(applicationMainWindow,hMenu);`

Each program can use various methods to handle user keyboard input. In this case probably is used GetAsyncKeyState or GetKeyState (for Ctrl) if you didn't send it and Ctrl is detected.

If it won't help you, please add code with your PostMessage to your question.

BTW. Instead of destroying GetSystemMenu you can clear appropriate window style and after sending input restore it (if the problem is System Menu - probability near 1%).

Comment: Trying them, will give bounty if any leads to solution. I'll also post the code I ended up using.

Comment: **1)** didn't work, caused the window to stop redrawing completely  **2)** "dangerous" as in program crashes, or bluescreen and reboot, or a lasting problem? **3)** `SetMenu(appwin,0);` didn't work, made the menu disappear. I tried various other `ModifyMenu` `RemoveMenu` directly removing the specific sub Menu items or the entire `"File"` menu. No luck. I think the keyboard hooks are set when the menu is created by the program, modifying the menu itself doesn't impact them.

Comment: I found a way, but can't say it's related to your solutions. Thanks for your help, I learned a lot

Comment: "Dangerous" means that starting an application may crash immediatelly. Like Hooks. Then you also cannot run taskmgr.exe... 

I think the application registers shortcuts or uses GetAsyncKeyState. Removing any menu item should also remove defined shortcut.

Comment: "
1) didn't work, caused the window to stop redrawing completely" - s=GetWindowLong(h,GWL_STYLE); SetWindowLong(h,GWL_STYLE,s|WS_DISABLED). This shouldn't block redrawing. Note single pipe character.

Comment: 1) It still redrew and it blocked input... including the simulated key presses unfortunately.

Comment: how about it? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646368(v=vs.85).aspx

Instead of modify the exe file?

You can use hooks to call it in context of destination application.

Comment: looks promising, I will try it later

Comment: probably tou need load accelerators one time and destroy the accelerators table twice. It is very possible, the returned handle is constant.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding a substitute for `MAKEINTRESOURCE(9)` in C#. If I understand correctly I need to feed that value to `LoadAccelerators` and use the IntPtr returns with `DestroyAcceleratorTable`. It looks like it probably returns the same value every time, since it doesn't even need the `hwnd`.

Comment: I have no experience in C#. In c++ the MAKEINTRESOURCE(x) is equivalent of (char*)(x). It means the 9 should be converted to intPtr or pointer. You should also retest your application on Win2000 to Win10. Behaviour for them can be different sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Although I didn't end up using this method, (because changing the menus was ineffectual for blocking the shortcuts for those menu items), I found various interesting ways to modify a third party window's menus. I'll leave some of what I found here because while it relate to my question, it doesn't solve my problem. Comments are based on my fallible understanding of what they do.

Various externals:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
//get hMenu of the window's menu
static extern IntPtr GetMenu(IntPtr hWnd);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
//Attach hMenu to a window. if hMenu is 0, attach no menu (remove menu)
static extern bool SetMenu(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hMenu);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
//Destroy hMenu
private static extern bool DestroyMenu(IntPtr hMenu);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
//Destroy Destroy submenu at position within menu
private static extern bool DeleteMenu(IntPtr hMenu, uint uPosition, uint uFlags);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
//Like GetMenu, but gets the restore/move/size/minimize/etc menu that you get when clicking on the little icon in the top left of a window (not the window's menu
private static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
//Adds a menu to a menu
private static extern bool AppendMenu(IntPtr hMenu, int uFlags, int uIDNewItem, string lpNewItem);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
//Removes a menu from a menu
private static extern bool RemoveMenu(IntPtr hMenu, uint uPosition, int uFlags);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
//Like AppendMenu, but specifies position
private static extern bool InsertMenu(IntPtr hMenu, int uPosition, int uFlags, int uIDNewItem, string lpNewItem);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
//Lets you set various properties of a menu (grayed out, checked, etc)
private static extern bool ModifyMenu(IntPtr hMenu, uint uPosition, uint uFlags, IntPtr uIDNewItem, string lpNewItem);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
//gets the hMenu for a submenu
private static extern IntPtr GetSubMenu(IntPtr hMenu, int pos);
```

Notes on their parameters:

`hWnd` is the handle of a window with a standard menu.

`hMenu` is the menu handle, which can be the handle of the root level menu (Like File, Edit, Help) or a submenu item (Like open, copy, About ...). You can get these with `GetSubMenu` or `GetSystemMenu` or

`uPosition` is an integer position, 0 being the first one.

`uFlags` can be found on each function's individual page which you can find at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468865%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

`lpNewItem` refers to the string of text shown on the menu item.

`uIDNewItem` is a pointer like `hMenu` that will get inserted at the defined location